# visual code change c# code error messages language to English

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a windows 10 machine set to french
and i have an English version of visual code but the error messages are shown in french see picture below :
[image]

how can i show them in English please

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales - did you try `The locale can also be changed by editing the argv.json file directly (Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments) and restarting VS Code.`

Comment: Can you not set the machine language to English? Windows will support multiple languages - you can add English and leave French as the default - just selecting English when you want it.

Comment: Maybe you are facing this - https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2513

Comment: @RandRandom thanks you very much , it was related to omnisharp

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.